# Hover-styling a width on a flexible height content box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a hover effect on a flexible content box that changes the width of an inner box to reveal text inside. I need this box to be flexible in height so that more content can be added, however, I don't want the height to change as I hover.

I've linked below what I've got so far, the box on the left shows my desired effect with a static height and box on the right shows what happens when I add more text which causes the issue of the height changing as I hover by wrapping the text inside it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ndpty6xa/

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 0%;
  height: 90%;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover>.content {
  width: 90%;
}

@media(max-width: 450px) {
  .flex {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .box {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=flex>

  <div class=box>
    <div class=content>
      <div class=text>
        <h3>This</h3>
        <p>Works</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=box>
    <div class=content>
      <div class=text>
        <h3>This doesnt</h3>
        <p>TestTe stTestTestTest TestTestTestT estTestT estTes tTestTe stTestTestTest</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I don't think I'm very good at explaining this but hopefully, someone gets the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think differently and instead of animating width you animate an overlay above it to simulate the same effect:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}
.content:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:red;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.content:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:50%;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:red;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.box:hover>.content:before {
  left: 100%;
}
.box:hover>.content:after {
  right: 100%;
}

@media(max-width: 450px) {
  .flex {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .box {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>This</h3>
        <p>Works</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>This also works!</h3>
        <p>TestTe stTestTestTest TestTestTestT estTestT estTes tTestTe stTestTestTest</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add **min-height** like **min-width** to box

```
.box{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```